# SharePoint 2013 Menus

Tags: navigation, office-365

In 2007 and 2010 versions of SharePoint, I was able to have drop down navigation menus that listed my sub-sites. I'm looking to accomplish the same thing in 2013 (O365) and haven't figured out how yet.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature is enabled in your Site Collection Features.  Then in Site Settings under "Look and Feel" you'll find the "Navigation" option that allows you to manage your menus and create drop down menu items in the top link bar.

Comment: Alright I got that. Now I'm working on the css and have the word wraping break problem fixed. I just can't figure out how to make the shadow box expand to be wider.